# ElasticSearch Facets / Aggregations sorting / ordering

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Does anyone know how to order aggregation / facet buckets from a range into a predictable order i/e the order they were added to the facet in?

Currently the 1.4 branch (and possibly older branches) order the buckets by "doc_count" which is not predictable. I want to be able to output the buckets in a pre-defined order.

Comment: What do you mean by a pre-defined order? Please clarify your requirement.

Comment: An order that I can set, for example returning the buckets in the order that I requested them instead of ordering them by "doc_count"

Comment: else allow me to add an arbitrary field to the buckets that will be returned in the bucket for example a label or some identifier so I might work things out for myself...

Comment: Do you have any specific requirement?

Comment: Yes, to be able to define the order they're returned in. For example I would like to list things like this....

Today (1)
Yesterday (5)
3 Days Ago (3)
5 Days Ago (1)

and so on but currently ES returns them in order or "Yesterday, 3 Days Ago, 5 Days ago, Today".... which is very unpredictable and not at all how to promote a good UX where lists should be in some ordered form. This is how SOLR currently works so I know it's possible in Lucene itself

Comment: Not sure if that can be done but you can also sort the buckets in the client itself I guess. By the way, did you look at `order` field in Terms aggregation?

Comment: These are range aggregations not terms. Sure the client can sort the buckets but when you use the date math library (now/1d etc) to do date ranges this becomes very very difficult to predict the keys / values to sort on. Secondly, ES should not be taking away the option to have the response sorted or not.

Comment: Turns out one can add a "key" to the range - another piece of undocumented information!

Comment: A possible solution, not tried, that comes to me is through using https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_script_score in order to change score as you desire, for example, docs 1 day ago = 1 score, 2 days ago = 0.5 , 5 days ago 0.1 ... and so on. And finally use `sort: _score` in query context.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to order them at at your end on the response from Elasticsearch. Another way could be order by term (key of the aggregation).

Update:

If you are using date range aggregation with query like below then the result will be automatically in the chronological order of "3 days ago", "yesterday", "today" irrespective of doc_count.

```
 {
   "aggs" : {
       "timerange" : {
           "date_range" : {
               "field" : "day",
               "keyed" : true,
               "ranges" : [
                {
                    "key": "today",
                    "from": "now/d"
                }
                ,
                {
                    "key": "yesterday",
                    "from": "now-1d/d",
                    "to": "now/d"
                },
                {
                    "key": "3 days ago",
                    "from": "now-3d/d",
                    "to": "now-2d/d"
                }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

If you are interested in daily data then a [Date histogram](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) will be more convenient.

Comment: Once more, theses are RANGE queries.

Comment: I have made some edits to the original answer. Let me know if I am understanding your problem correctly

Comment: That's a very hacky answer to always expect the bucket keys to be sortable due to how they're labelled but thanks anyway. I chose to do the sorting at the client side